# Atmega328P CTC assembly error

Tags: assembly, timer, arduino, atmega

I'm trying to use the CTC (Clear Timer on Compare) method for using the timer but I can not write to the registers to try to enable that mode. The complete data sheet can be found [HERE](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATMEGA328P.aspx?tab=documents). P.144 explains how the idea works but not how to actually implement in code.

I have tried using the OCR2A (Output Compare Register) by trying to set a value to it, but get a build error when trying to set its value.

I get a few errors when trying to set the value of OCR2A or TCCR2A.
The errors are either `Operand 1 out of range` or `Invalid Register`

Any advice or direction would be helpfull

```
.def AllOnes = R16
.def ChargeState = R17
.def AllZeros = R18
.def PushButn = R19
.def TimerValue = R20

MAIN:
   LDI AllOnes, 0xFF    ; assign 1 - make an output
   LDI ChargeState, 0x00    ; start with all the LEDS ON; Holds the Light Pattern
   LDI AllZeros, 0x00   ; assign 0 - make an input
   LDI PushButn, 0x00   ; to hold the value read from PORTB0

   SBI COM2A1,0 ; set the Output compare pin for 
   SBI TIFR2, 1 ; set the Output compare Flag; i.e OCF2A

   ;According to the breakout board, PORTB5 is connected on spot 13 on the board
   OUT DDRD, AllOnes    ;set PORT D as an output

   ;make PORTB an input
   OUT DDRB, AllZeros   ;set PORT B as an input

   ;Start by turning all LEDS OFF
   OUT PORTD, ChargeState



OFFSTATE:   ;state for when the lights are off
   ;check if the button has been pressed.
   IN PushButn, PINB
   SBRC PushButn, 0
   JMP OFFSTATE
   JMP CHARGING

CHARGING:
   LDI ChargeState, 0x01
   OUT PORTD, ChargeState
   ;display the state of the first charge state

   ;initialize the value for the Output Comare Register (OCR2A)
   ;SBI OCR2A, 0

LOOP:
    CP TCCR0A, COM2A1
    JMP LOOP
```

Answer (score 1):

I think answer is: there is no instruction to do it. See *Register Summary* and *Instruction Set Summary* table in datasheet.
*SBI OCR2A,0* cannot be used because *OCR2A* is in upper address register space. Compare to *SBI TIFR2, 1* where *TIFR1* is in lower space.
Similarly *CP TCCR0A, COM2A1* you cannot compare against IO register. Use

```
MOV R0,TCCR0A
CPI R0,COM2A1
```

or so. Sorry written by heart, hopefully syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out TCCR0A has COM2A1, which is an output register. To write to it you have to use `OUT`